# I am trying to reverse the word of string but I am getting argument out of range exception. DONT USE SPLIT, CONCAT OR ANY INBUILT METHOD

Tags: c#, string, reverse

I am trying to reverse the word of string but I am getting argument out of range exception.

- Input - `I am good`
- Output- `good am I`

Below is the code and exception snipet is attached in code -

```
        string s = Console.ReadLine();
        
        int i = s.Length - 1;

        string ans = "";

        while (i >= 0)
        {
            while (i >= 0 && s[i] == ' ') i--;
            int j=i;

            if (i < 0) break;

            while (i >= 0 && s[i] != ' ') i--;

            if (ans == string.Empty)
            {
                ans = (string)ans.Concat(s.Substring(i+1,j+1));
            }
            else
            {
                ans = (string)ans.Concat(" " + s.Substring(i+1, j+1));
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine(ans);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: You might want to read [this blog post](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: I don't understand your edit - why did you place that massive all-caps disclaimer into your title? It doesn't make sense. Regardless: you need to edit your question to create a [mcve], including all necessary info (including not only your relevant code, but also the expected vs actual behavior, errors, and relevant debugging information). Right now, it's code, one input sample, and mention of an exception, without any specifics about where that exception occurred, values of variables when the exception occurred, etc. This means you've left everything up to the Community.